# response code 502 is given by maven install

Tags: java, maven

i have a project with its pom file and i am tring to build it with mvn install command but its failed

i got the following error

```
INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:17 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-26T09:32:31+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/112M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project PROJECT-web: Could not resolve dependencies for project co
m.prod.PROJECT:PROJECT-web:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.prod.comp:PROJECT
-web:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.prod.comp:comp-web:jar:0.0.1-S
NAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact com.prod.comp:comp-web:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT from/to prodLocalRe
p (http://121.0.0.44:8080/artifactory/prod-repo): Error transferring file: Server returned HTTP res
ponse code: 502 for URL: http://121.0.0.44:8080/artifactory/prod-repo/com/prod/comp/comp-web/0.0.1
-SNAPSHOT/comp-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom from http://121.0.0.44:8080/artifactory/prod-repo/com/prod/G
ACA/comp-web/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/comp-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom with proxyInfo ProxyInfo{host='compproxy', u
serName='null', port=8080, type='http', nonProxyHosts='null'} -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project PROJECT-we
b: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.prod.PROJECT:PROJECT-web:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Fail
ed to collect dependencies at com.prod.comp:comp-web:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

**note that:** maven downloaded many jars but stopped with this error

**so my question is** if i understood the error right are there some jars that prod-repo is running on their own reprository and servers?

**the pom.xml**

Comment: seems like your settings.xml has issues with the proxy

Comment: @OhadR i have suspected that and try it on another project but it works fine

Comment: please give more info about your system - firewall, repo etc. and post your settings.xml and pom.xml

Comment: @OhadR thanks for tiring to help i got my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 502 error message indicates that the server **behind** the proxy is not available. Now from the stacktrace it's hard to figure out if that is the server behind http://121.0.0.44:8080 or that it's another maven repository which is being questioned for a an artifact.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the proxy setting were different between IntelliJ-HTTP_Proxy & setting.xml under .m2 folder.

I cleared proxy setting on my m2 and kept IntelliJ proxy setting and issue got resolved.